# Does APEX support factory enum method from value idiom?

Tags: apex, enum

Apex is supposed to be based on Java which supports [factory method in enums types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-a-string-value-in-java).

```
global enum CheckResult {
    PENDING, PASSED, FAILED;

    public static CheckResult fromResult(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (aBoolean) {
            return PASSED;
        } else {
            return FAILED;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find a form that actually compiles, is this a supported feature in apex, if so how is it achieved in apex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apex does support [`enum`'s](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_enums.htm), syntax is bit different than java though.

Proper class based on your example would be as:

```
public class CheckResult {
    public Enum Result { PENDING, PASSED, FAILED}

    public static Result fromResult(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (aBoolean) {
            return Result.PASSED;
        } else {
            return Result.FAILED;
        }
    }
}
```

You could verify the result from execute anonymous from developer console:

```
CheckResult.Result result = CheckResult.fromResult(true);
// this would be equal to enum value passed
System.debug(result == CheckResult.Result.PASSED);
```

Comment: That is great, I have several external checks to be made via REST that returns true or false results via JSON, each exist in salesforce as pending when the record is created but passed/failed as the process completes  Your method will work perfectly since I wanted to avoid the conditional testing all over the code base.

Comment: simplest code: `return aBoolean ? Result.PASSED : Result.FAILED;`

Comment: @cropredy I value clarity over brevity

Comment: @MartinofHessle - perfectly understandable. I was like you when I started with Apex but over time certain idioms became natural and I learned to value terseness (fewer lines).